# Can you create a constant (read-only) state variable in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Can you declare a constant variable in Solidity?

```
const uint answer = 42;
```

Or is the only way to do it with a const function?

```
function GetAnswer() constant returns(uint ret) {
  return 42;
}
```

I know you could always create a normal public variable and then just not have any setters in the code, but this is not immediate obvious from the declaration, so it seems preferable to explicitly declare a variable as a constant or read-only if the language supports it.

Comment: minor nitpick: do you mean to cast a float to an `uint` here?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Found the answer:

> State variables can be declared as constant (this is not yet
> implemented for array and struct types and not possible for mapping
> types).

> ```
> contract C {
>     uint constant x = 32**22 + 8;
>     string constant text = "abc"; 
> }
> ```

> This has the effect that the compiler does not reserve a storage slot for these variables and every
> occurrence is replaced by their constant value.
>
> The value expression can only contain integer arithmetics.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#constant

(After following this link, you may have to click "Constant" in the left menu if the autoscroll doesn't work.)

Comment: In addition to Raine's answer, while declaring **constant** - you must not modify the state.

Comment: " the compiler does not reserve a storage slot for these variables" - does it mean we pay no gas for constants? 1 byte is 1 gas, so if I use a constant that normally takes 5 bytes we pay no gas. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

use `constant` like this in solidity:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.8.0 <0.9.0;

// any contract can use it
uint constant pi=314; 

contract C1{
    uint constant FavorateNumber=25;
    function getNumbers() public pure returns(uint){
        return FavorateNumber*pi;
    }
}
contract C2{
    function getPi() public pure returns(uint){
       return pi;
    }
}
```

you can use public, external, internal, and private with variables:

- `public`: anyone can get the value of a variable.
- `external`: only external functions can get the value of a local variable. It is not used on state variables.
- `internal`: only functions in this contract and related contracts can get values.
- `private`: access limited to functions from this contract.

Comment: Jul '22:  Has constant struct yet been implements ion solidity?