# Cheapest way to hardcode a value

Tags: gas

I have a smart contract that checks that the msg.sender is the owner. If I know that the owner address is 0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8 for example, then what is the cheapest way to hardcode this value that I use for checking msg.sender is this address

Option 1

```
function foo() {
require(msg.sender == 0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8)
}
```

option 2

```
function call() {
 return 0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8
}

function foo() {
require(msg.sender == call())
}
```

option 3

```
address owner = 0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8

function foo() {
require(msg.sender == owner)
}
```

Which way is cheaper and why ?

Comment: Probably Use constant is the cheapest way like option 3 but with constant keyword. And then u can use it in many functions and not just 1

Comment: using a constant like in option 3 puts it in storage which is the most expensive method (If my understanding is correct)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you create a constant (read-only) state variable in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/can-you-create-a-constant-read-only-state-variable-in-solidity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a concrete experiment, tested with solidity `v0.8.11` -

**Option 1**

```
contract Greeter {
    uint public x = 0;

    constructor() {
    }

    function foo() public {
        require(msg.sender == address(0x7D70653a55BcAc5B96c02FADcaC7f4272C1642B9));
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

Deployment: 115,183 gas

Call foo():  41,256 gas

**Option 2**

```
contract Greeter {
    uint public x = 0;

    constructor() {
    }

    function call() internal pure returns (address) {
        return address(0x7D70653a55BcAc5B96c02FADcaC7f4272C1642B9);
    }

    function foo() public {
        require(msg.sender == call());
        x = 1;
    }

}
```

Deployment: 117,973 gas

Call foo():  41,291 gas

**Option 3**

```
contract Greeter {
    uint public x = 0;

    address owner = address(0x7D70653a55BcAc5B96c02FADcaC7f4272C1642B9);

    function foo() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

Deployment: 140,392 gas

Call foo():  42,092 gas

**Option 4**

```
contract Greeter {
    uint public x = 0;

    address constant owner = address(0x7D70653a55BcAc5B96c02FADcaC7f4272C1642B9);

    function foo() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

Deployment: 115,171 gas

Call foo():  41,256 gas

---

Summary

Option 4 and option 1 are about the same and the cheapest both to deploy and to call. Option 1 is slightly more expensive to deploy.

That is because a `constant` is about the same as a hardcoded value, both do not occupy storage space. But you need the keyword `constant` for it to be treated as such (was missing from option 3).

So always use `constant` where possible, better than s

Comment: Can you indicate the solidity version used in the tests? I'd only add that the costs applies to the examples, in a real contract depending on the usage the values obtained could be different.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way would be the constant approach as constants do not get a storage entry assigned and are stored as values along with the contract. For more information consult the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#constants)

Comment: Does the option 1 store it as a constant as well like option 3? Then 1 would be slightly cheaper because we are declaring it directly instead of creating a constant for it ?

Comment: none of the presented options contain constants as far as i can see

Comment: Isn't the first one a constant since obviously code itself is immutable ? if not what is the type of addres in option 1 is it?

Comment: If you read the documentation i've mentioned, it is explaining how a constant is different from an immutable variable.

Comment: yes, when you use constant owner = 0xe.... it will simply replace every instance of owner in contract by the address. if I do (msg.sender == owner) isn'T it the same or as (msg.sender == 0xe...) which might be slightly more gas efficiant? Or are you saying that in option1 the address is actually an immutable variable

Comment: I am not able to test it atm, but i believe the constant keyword is what triggers the storing in the contract. It might be that its set as an immutable variable yes.